# UIView.animate not animating bool value perfectly

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, swift3

I tried to animate isHidden, it seems working ok, but if I mistakenly animate **isHidden=false** 5 times by setting `yes` to true 5 times, then sometimes I should animate **isHidden=true** 2 or more time to make my UIView visible!

Am I missing something?

```
if (yes)
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay:0, animations: {
                myLabel.isHidden=false
            }
}
else
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay:0, animations: {
                myLabel.isHidden=true
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not animate a view's "isHidden" parameter. You should animate its alpha.

```
if (yes)
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay:0, animations: {
                myLabel.alpha=1.0
            }
}
else
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay:0, animations: {
                myLabel.alpha=0.0
            }
}
```

-- UPDATE --

If you want to make the view hidden after the animation you can use this:

```
myLabel.isHidden=false
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
    myLabel.alpha=1.0
  }, completion: { finished in

  })

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
    myLabel.alpha=0.0
  }, completion: { finished in
    myLabel.isHidden=true
  })
```

Comment: But I need to animate isHidden so after it's removed from view the autolayout shrinks the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is that you are using linear animation on Bool type which has only 2 values (false = 0, true = 1) and any other values between that (it's pulse).

Try this:

```
if (yes)
{
    myLabel.alpha = 0
    myLabel.isHidden = false
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                myLabel.alpha = 1
            })
}
else
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                myLabel.alpha = 0
            }, completion: { (status) in
                myLabel.isHidden = true
            })
}
```

Comment: But I need to animate isHidden so after it's removed from view the autolayout shrinks the layout.

Comment: So try to animate with alpha property also height of `UILabel` frame.